# Go, Appengine, SMTP, Gmail

Tags: google-app-engine, go, smtp

For some reason I cannot figure out how to send emails using a gmail account, Appengine and Golang.

Here's what I've done:

I went to Google Cloud Platform > Appengine > Settings > Select Project and I added the gmail account on Email API authorized senders.

I' tried to make this work using the code from (https://golang.org/pkg/net/smtp/#pkg-examples)  (func SendMail)

---

```
package main

import (

    "log"
    "net/smtp"
)

func main() {

    // Set up authentication information.
    auth := smtp.PlainAuth("", "user@gmail.com", "password", "smtp.gmail.com")

    // Connect to the server, authenticate, set the sender and recipient,
    // and send the email all in one step.
    to := []string{"recipient@example.net"}
    msg := []byte("To: recipient@example.net\r\n" +
        "Subject: discount Gophers!\r\n" +
        "\r\n" +
        "This is the email body.\r\n")
    err := smtp.SendMail(smtp.gmail.com:587", auth, "sender@example.org", to, msg)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

On the front-end (JavaScript) I get an unsuccessful response after trying to run this code.

I've been running this on the appengine staging server

I tried different smtp server, ports, users and it still not work (support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en)

I found a few examples on github and some other blog and I tried them but it didn't make different.
github.com/golang/go/wiki/SendingMail

nathanleclaire.com/blog/2013/12/17/sending-email-from-gmail-using-golang/

On all the examples it everything looks straight forward but there's something that I'm definitely missing or misunderstanding.

Comment: FYI:
I've just successfully sent an email with your code using my gmail account.

Comment: Did you use the code locally or on Google Appengine.  There are few things that work slightly different on App engine.

Comment: locally. hm... then my only guess is ports. Will telnet smtp.gmail.com 587 work from your instance?

Comment: I tried it but it won't telnet smtp.gmail.com 587 from the appengine container.  I know that there's a gmail api on Google Cloud Platform but I was hoping to send email in a simple way using smtp before trying to there.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought. Additionally, I see that app engine does not allow standard ports (https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail/ ).

Comment: I will do that.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There're some limitations with establishing raw tcp connections on GAE: 
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/sockets/#limitations_and_restrictions

I would recommend to use GAE mail api (which is slightly diffrent from standart smtp package) to send emails:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/mail/sending-receiving-with-mail-api

Comment: I will do that.  I appreciate your help!

Comment: note that GAE mail api only works in the standard environment. ie. does not work if you are using the flexible environment. see https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/migrating#mail